# Why Do Thermal Operations Form a Semigroup?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-information

Given a fixed "background temperature" $T$ and an $n$-dimensional system, the set of thermal operations is usually defined to be
$$
\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}\Big\{ \operatorname{tr}_B\Big(U\Big((\cdot)\otimes \frac{e^{-H_B/kT}}{\operatorname{tr}(e^{-H_B/kT})}\Big)U^*\Big) :\ \substack{H_B\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}\text{ hermitian}\\ U\in\mathbb C^{nm\times nm}\text{ unitary, }[U,H_S\otimes\textbf{1}_B+\textbf{1}_S\otimes H_B]=0 }\Big\}
$$
cf. Sec. 1.3 in [Lostaglio, Rep. Prog. Phys. 82 114001 (2019)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1361-6633/ab46e5) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11549)). In other words---as Lostaglio writes on the bottom of page 6---thermal operations are compositions of "preparing thermal states at a fixed temperature $T$ and with arbitrary Hamiltonian $H_B$, performing energy-preserving unitaries, and tracing out subsystems" where the dimension of the bath is arbitrary (but finite).

In the same review article Lostaglio recalls that a resource theory is defined by---among other things--a subset $\mathcal A$ of all quantum channels ("allowed operations") which is closed under composition and includes the identity; in other words $\mathcal A$ has to be a semigroup with identity which does make sense from an operational point of view. Thus the question I had for a while was the following:

> Is the set of thermal operations---as defined above---closed under composition? And if so, why?

On the one hand, this whole construction is known under the name "resource theory of thermal operations" so the implied answer is yes, **yet** I have seen neither this explicit statement nor any computation justifying this result anywhere until now. It turns out that the computation is rather elementary---although non-trivial---so I would like to answer my own question by providing a short proof below.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two elements of the set of thermal operations, with unitaries $U$ and $U'$ and Hamiltonians $H_B$ and $H_{B'}$, respectively. Following your convention, I will write $\gamma_\bullet=\frac{e^{-H_\bullet/kT}}{\operatorname{tr}(e^{-H_\bullet/kT})}$.

Then, the concatenation of both thermal operators is the map
$$
\rho\to \mathrm{tr}\big[U_{SB}U'_{SB'}(\rho_S\otimes\gamma_B\otimes\gamma_{B'})(U_{SB}U'_{SB'})^\dagger\big]\ .
$$
That is, the map is of the form of a thermal operation
$$
\rho\to \mathrm{tr}\big[V(\rho_S\otimes\gamma_{BB'}V^\dagger\big]\ ,
$$
where we define $\gamma_{BB'}:=\gamma_{B}\otimes\gamma_{B'}$ and $V:=U_{SB}U'_{SB'}$. It remains to show that $V$ and $\gamma_{BB'}$ have the necessary properties:

- $\gamma_{BB'}%=\gamma_{B}\otimes\gamma_{B'} = \frac{e^{-H_B/kT}}{\operatorname{tr}(e^{-H_B/kT})} \otimes \frac{e^{-H_{B'}/kT}}{\operatorname{tr}(e^{-H_{B'}/kT})}=\frac{e^{-H_{BB'}/kT}}{\operatorname{tr}(e^{-H_{BB'}/kT})}$ is the thermal state of $H_{BB'}=H_B\otimes I_{B'}+I_B\otimes H_{B'}$.
- $V=U_{SB}U'_{SB'}$ and $H_S+H_{BB'}=H_S + H_{B}+H_{B'}$
  (I omit the identities) commute: $U'_{SB'}$ commutes with $H_S+H_{B'}$ and with $H_B$ (the latter trivially), and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

All we have to do is take two thermal operations and show that their composition again has the form of a thermal operation. Thus given two bath Hamiltonians $H_B\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$, $H_{B'}\in\mathbb C^{m'\times m'}$ and unitaries $U\in\mathbb C^{nm\times nm}$, $V\in\mathbb C^{nm'\times nm'}$ which satisfy
$$
[U,H_S\otimes\textbf{1}_B+\textbf{1}_S\otimes H_B]=0\quad\text{ and }\quad [V,\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes H_S+H_{B'}\otimes\textbf{1}_S]=0\tag{1}
$$
we consider the map
$$
\rho\mapsto \operatorname{tr}_{B'}(V(\gamma_{B'}\otimes \boxed{\operatorname{tr}_B(U(\rho\otimes\gamma_B)U^*)})V^*)\tag{2}
$$
Here we used the isomorphism $S\otimes B\otimes B'\simeq B'\otimes S\otimes B$ to shift the second bath to the first tensor factor; this will simplify the computation but of course does not affect the result itself. Also $\gamma_B$ ($\gamma_{B'}$) is short for the thermal state on $B$ ($B'$) with respect to the Hamiltonian $H_B$ ($H_{B'}$) and the fixed temperature $T$.

A common trick to show that two states (or two channels) coïncide is to show that all their expectation values coïncide; this is especially useful here as the partial trace is characterized by the duality relation $\operatorname{tr}(X\operatorname{tr}_B(A))=\operatorname{tr}((X\otimes\textbf{1}_B)A)$. Thus let arbitrary $X\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ be given. We compute
$$
\operatorname{tr}\big(X\operatorname{tr}_{B'}(V(\gamma_{B'}\otimes \operatorname{tr}_B(U(\rho\otimes\gamma_B)U^*))V^*)\big)=\operatorname{tr}\big(V^*(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes X)V\big(\gamma_{B'}\otimes \operatorname{tr}_B(U(\rho\otimes\gamma_B)U^*)\big)\big)\,.
$$
The non-trivial (yet somehow intuitive) result we now need is that the partial trace over $B$ "commutes with" attaching the bath $B'$ if the $B'$-part of the system is "in a product state". More formally we use that for all $A\in\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H_1)$ and all $C\in\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H_2\otimes\mathcal H_3)$ one has $\operatorname{tr}_3 (A\otimes C)=A\otimes\operatorname{tr}_3(C)$ (where $\operatorname{tr}_3$ is the partial trace over $\mathcal H_3$), cf. also the footnote at the bottom. This yields
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}\big(X\operatorname{tr}_{B'}(...)\big)&=\operatorname{tr}\big(V^*(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes X)V \operatorname{tr}_B(\gamma_{B'}\otimes U(\rho\otimes\gamma_B)U^*))\big)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\big(\big((V^*(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes X)V)\otimes\mathbf{1}_B\big) (\gamma_{B'}\otimes U(\rho\otimes\gamma_B)U^*))\big)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\big((V^*\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes X\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U) (\gamma_{B'}\otimes \rho\otimes\gamma_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U^*)\big)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\Big(X\operatorname{tr}_{B,B'}\big((V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U) (\gamma_{B'}\otimes \rho\otimes\gamma_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U^*)(V^*\otimes \textbf{1}_B)\big)\Big)
\end{align*}
Finally, because $X$ was chosen arbitrarily, we see that the channel from eq.(2) is the same as
$$
\rho\mapsto\operatorname{tr}_{B,B'}\big((V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U) (\gamma_{B'}\otimes \rho\otimes\gamma_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U^*)(V^*\otimes \textbf{1}_B)\big)\,.
$$
Most importantly this is a thermal operation generated by the "bath Hamiltonian" $H_B\otimes\textbf{1}_{B'}+\textbf{1}_B\otimes H_{B'}\in\mathbb C^{mm'\times mm'}$ (so the corresponding thermal state is $\gamma_B\otimes\gamma_{B'}$; direct computation) and the unitary $(V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U)\in\mathbb C^{nmm'\times nmm'}$. Finally, a straightforward computation shows that the "large" unitary is energy-conserving:
\begin{align*}
(V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)&(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U)(\mathbf{1}_{B'}\otimes H_S\otimes\mathbf{1}_B+\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes\mathbf{1}_S\otimes H_B+H_{B'}\otimes\textbf{1}_S\otimes\textbf{1}_B)\\
&=(V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)\big( \mathbf{1}_{B'}\otimes(U(H_S\otimes\mathbf{1}_{B}+\mathbf{1}_{S}\otimes H_B))+H_{B'}\otimes U\big)\\
&\overset{(1)}=(V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)\big( \mathbf{1}_{B'}\otimes((H_S\otimes\mathbf{1}_{B}+\mathbf{1}_{S}\otimes H_B)U)+(H_{B'}\otimes\textbf{1}_S\otimes\textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U)\big)\\
&= (V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(\mathbf{1}_{B'}\otimes H_S\otimes\mathbf{1}_B+\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes\mathbf{1}_S\otimes H_B+H_{B'}\otimes\textbf{1}_S\otimes\textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U) \\
=\ldots&= (\mathbf{1}_{B'}\otimes H_S\otimes\mathbf{1}_B+\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes\mathbf{1}_S\otimes H_B+H_{B'}\otimes\textbf{1}_S\otimes\textbf{1}_B)(V\otimes \textbf{1}_B)(\textbf{1}_{B'}\otimes U)
\end{align*}
This shows that the thermal operations indeed form a semigroup which concludes the proof. $\square$

---

<sub>Footnote: For anyone who wants to see why this partial trace identity holds: Recall that the partial trace over a space with orthonormal basis $\langle g_n\rangle_{n\in\mathcal N}$ satisfies $\langle \psi|\operatorname{tr}_B(A)|\phi\rangle=\sum_{n\in\mathcal N}\langle \psi\otimes g_n|A|\phi\otimes g_n\rangle$. This lets us compute
\begin{align*}
\langle x\otimes y, \operatorname{tr}_3 (A\otimes C) (z\otimes w)\rangle&= \sum_{n\in\mathcal N}\langle x\otimes y\otimes g_n,(A\otimes C)(z\otimes w\otimes g_n)\rangle\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathcal N}\langle x,Az\rangle\langle y\otimes g_n,C(w\otimes g_n)\rangle=\langle x,Az\rangle\langle y,\operatorname{tr}_3(C)w\rangle =\langle x\otimes y,( A\otimes\operatorname{tr}_3(C)) (z\otimes w)\rangle
\end{align*}
for all $x,z\in\mathcal H_1$, $y,w\in\mathcal H_2$. By linearity this extends to all expectation values and thus the two operators coïncide.</sub>

Comment: This looks rather complicated!

Comment: To be fair, your answer is the concise version of my (admittedly rather detailed) computation. Of course summarizing the main idea in a comprehensive way---as you did---is always appreciated!